# How to import legacy js node_modules files in angular2 with webpack

Tags: javascript, import, angular, webpack, node-modules

I've a issue, I can't to import a BootstrapMenu in Angular2 with Bootstrap I met a difficulty when I want to import .js files with Webpack.

I get this error in my console :

```
Cannot find name 'BootstrapMenu'
```

I try to import BootStrapMenu like this :

```
import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap-menu/dist/BootstrapMenu.min.js';
```

This is my component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap-menu/dist/BootstrapMenu.min.js';

console.log('`Dashboard` component loaded asynchronously');

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
})

export class Dashboard {
    localState;

    constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route
            .data
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.localState = data.yourData;


     });
            console.log('hello `Dashboard` component');


            var menu = new BootstrapMenu('.line', {
                .....
                .......
                }
        });

    }
    asyncDataWithWebpack() {

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help